# Setting GridBackground color overlays controls

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Trying to set the style in a resource, I have it set like this for a grid.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="#5B434343" />
```

then I set the grid to this style.

```
<Style TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

When I do this, It covers the entire grid like I want, but you cannot click any of the controls. Should this be behaving this way, where the background color is basically disabling the controls?

Comment: I take it the Grid in question is *on top of* the controls you're trying to click on? Try setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the Grid.

Comment: No, It goes Window -> Grid -> Rest of the controls.

Comment: If that's true, the problem isn't what you think it is. If you post enough XAML to reproduce the issue, somebody will be able to help you with it.